# Why are acoustic power loss never taken in account?

Tags: vibration, aeroacoustics

At university (I did mechanical engineering) I attended several courses in which energy balance was considered (e.g. thermal machines, electric machines, CFD...).
Each time a machine efficiency was investigated the loss terms taken in consideration were relative to various kinds of mechanical friction, thermal loss, hysteresis... but no term ever made reference to noise. Still some machines do produce a relevant amount of noise (e.g. fans, rotating machinery...), which should mean a waste of mechanical energy to the surrounding environment. So why is this never taken in consideration in theory?

Is it just because the loss fraction is negligible? If so, aren't there any applications for which this does not hold? And furthermore, does anyone know of a model used to quantify such losses?

Comment: An interesting topic.  One might categorize the noises into that which originates from the power source and that which eminates from the application.  Indeed, the sound from prop tips breaking the sound barrier is considered wasteful, as is noise from helicopter rotor blade interference.  Noise could **indicate** conditions such as higher friction (in the engine) or higher drag, but sound waves (we hear) are not as energetic as light waves or x-rays.

Comment: Did you ever ask one of your professors? They usually _love_ when someone asks a good question...

Comment: Didn't come to mind at the time

Comment: Not relevant to aviation, but it does make a difference at the microscale. If you have a vibrating beam maybe 100 micrometers long, acoustic power loss is THE dominant source of energy loss.

Answer (score 7):

Acoustic power density is too low to matter, even for very loud sustained sounds.

> The roar of a train engine or the whine of a pneumatic drill ... is
> about a hundredth of a watt per square meter.

-- https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-sound-be-converted-to-useful-energy/

It's also been said that for a cup of room temperature coffee to reach the boiling point, assuming perfect energy transfer from the acoustic energy of two people chatting there, it would take about three thousand years.

Comment: I think you're mistaken in your comparison. Energy loss is from the central point, whereas the energy you could hope to harvest is but one very small sliver of a rapidly growing sphere. Consider an incandescent light bulb vs an LED one. Neither one would power a solar cell effectively, but one is massively more efficient than the other. Similarly, as I read it the OP's question has more to do with how much more efficient a machine could be than how much we could extract from it. Of course, it's still a small amount of energy as you point out, just not for those reasons.

Comment: True, the MIT article omits the distance from the point source of the sound, but generously guessing 10 m, then the sphere's area is 420 m$^2$, so the total power is 420 mW.  For a jackhammer, never mind a locomotive, that's a fraction of a percent of its input power.